# MYSQL 12 hour time format stuck with leading 0, and wont convert to 24 hour format

Tags: mysql, time

I am bringing in data from a DB that has times in the 12-hour format. For some reason, the code that writes to the DB is writing the time sometimes as 3:30 pm and other times as 03:30 pm. I can not control that. I can however control how I am querying the data. I am trying to get it uniform so that all times return without the 0. EG all times of 3:30 pm would return as 3:30 pm, not 03:30 pm.

I have tried date format, time format string_to_date and nothing works. IF I convert it to a 24 hours time format by using `TIME_FORMAT(my_column_name,'%H:%i')` it converts 2 PM to 02:00. IF I don't convert it to the 24-hour format and use `TIME_FORMAT(my_column_name,'%l:%i')` it ignores my request not to have a leading 0.

The intial time is stored as a MetaKey in the longtext format. The program just places the time in there as it chooses as text

How do I fix this?

Comment: You haven't given us quite enough info to help you. Please [edit] your question. What is the data type of the column you are trying to format as `3:30pm`.  What do you see if you do `SELECT TIME_FORMAT(DeliveryTime, '%H:%i')` How about just `SELECT DeliveryTime`?

Comment: It is stored as a MetaKey actually and a longext

Comment: If you're storing time or date information in a database, it almost always makes the most sense to store it in a native format rather than as a longtext. You'll then be able to do all kinds of nifty things like query by time, or display all the times consistently without having to do all kinds of display transformations to remove a leading zero. I'd recommend solving your problem by storing the time in an appropriate column type instead of the longtext one.